# Copy file from remote server to local drive only within a range

Tags: ssl, unix, ssh, command-line, remote-server

My data stored in a remote server and update every day like 16062021.csv , 15062021.csv etc. I would like to copy file from remote server to my local pc only with a specific range via shell .

This snippet will copy all the data to my computer but I want only n weeks data not the whole n year.
How can I specify a date range here and only copy 16042021.csv to 16062021.csv?

```
ROBOCOPY "\\103.241.144.137\files" "C:\Users\Documents\my_path" /mir
```

Answer (score 0):

If using Robocopy from Windows, it has options:
MAXimum file AGE - exclude files older than n days/date.
Also /MINAGE:n :
MINimum file AGE - exclude files newer than n days/date.

This relies on backup files that have timestamps similar to names.
Options are easy to see, so if this is not a solution, please explain.

Comment: I think you are suggesting like this. right? ROBOCOPY "\\103.241.144.137\files\MAXAGE:5\copyall" "C:\Users\Documents\my_path" /mir . erroe is "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect" but they are correct

Comment: ROBOCOPY "\\103.241.144.137\files" "C:\Users\Documents\my_path"  /MIR /COPYALL /MAXAGE:35    if you want 5 weeks - but you must have rights on source.

Comment: thanks. still getting same error , I have a access right and file names are correct. I need to investigate it more